# Kernel crashes when accessing socket buffer structure

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module

I've been trying to intercept connect system call in an attempt to rewrite destination ip address of tcp request. I think I successfully retrieved address of the connect system call from the symbol table and intercept it. My conclusion is based on the fact that my function gets called by the kernel. However, I'm not so sure about if my code is in fact intercepting connect system call. In order to verify that I tried to print out the ip address of either source or destination. But whenever I try to access socket buffer structure, kernel crashes. You can see that section of the code in hijackConnect function and they are commented out. I would like to know what I am doing wrong and how can I make sure that I'm really intercepting tcp requests. If possible, I would like to know how to rewrite destination ip address so that I can redirect http requests to particular web sites. Even if you don't know how to go about doing that, I still appreciate good pointer and learning resources.

Disclaimer : I'm not trying to do anything sinister. This is for kernel hacking school project and it has to be done in kernel space. My kernel is Version 3.16 and the following codes are adaption of online tutorials to my own need.

```
#define DISABLE_WRITE_PROTECTION (write_cr0(read_cr0() & (~ 0x10000)))
#define ENABLE_WRITE_PROTECTION (write_cr0(read_cr0() | 0x10000))

static unsigned long **find_sys_call_table(void); 
asmlinkage int hijackConnect(struct sock *sk, struct sockaddr *uaddr,int addr_len);

asmlinkage int (*original_sys_connect)(struct sock *, struct sockaddr *, int);
asmlinkage unsigned long **sys_call_table;

/* Initialisation routine */
int init_module(void)
{
    sys_call_table = find_sys_call_table();

    if(!sys_call_table) {
       printk(KERN_ERR "Couldn't find sys_call_table.\n");
       return -EPERM;  /* operation not permitted; couldn't find general error */
    }

    DISABLE_WRITE_PROTECTION;
    original_sys_connect = (void *) sys_call_table[SYS_CONNECT];
    sys_call_table[SYS_CONNECT] = (unsigned long *) hijackConnect;
    ENABLE_WRITE_PROTECTION;

    printk(KERN_INFO "Connect system call is hijacked!\n");

    return 0;
 }

/* Cleanup routine */
void cleanup_module(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Unhook hijacking\n");

    /* Restore the original sys_open in the table */
    DISABLE_WRITE_PROTECTION;
    sys_call_table[SYS_CONNECT] = (unsigned long *) original_sys_connect;
    ENABLE_WRITE_PROTECTION;
}

static unsigned long **find_sys_call_table() {
   unsigned long offset;
   unsigned long **sct;

    for(offset = PAGE_OFFSET; offset < ULLONG_MAX; offset += sizeof(void *)) {
       sct = (unsigned long **) offset;

       if(sct[__NR_close] == (unsigned long *) sys_close)
          return sct;
    }

    /*
     * Given the loop limit, it's somewhat unlikely we'll get here. I don't
     * even know if we can attempt to fetch such high addresses from memory,
     * and even if you can, it will take a while!
     */
   return NULL;
 }

 asmlinkage int hijackConnect(struct sock *sk, struct sockaddr *uaddr,int     addr_len)
 {
    printk(KERN_INFO "Connect is called!\n");

    /*  struct sockaddr_in *usin = (struct sockaddr_in *)uaddr;
    struct inet_sock *inet = inet_sk(sk);
    struct tcp_sock *tp = tcp_sk(sk);
    __be16 orig_sport, orig_dport;
    __be32 daddr, nexthop, test;

    orig_sport = inet->inet_sport;
    orig_dport = usin->sin_port;
    test = inet->inet_saddr;
    //daddr = usin->sin_addr.s_addr;

    printk(KERN_INFO "ADDRESS - %d", ntohl(test));*/
    return (*original_sys_connect)(sk,uaddr,addr_len); 
}
```

Comment: Correct definition of syscall function is `SYSCALL_DEFINE3(connect, int, fd, struct sockaddr __user *, uservaddr, int, addrlen)`. Note, that its second argument, `uservaddr`, has `__user` modifier of its type. This means given pointer points to *user address space*, and should be accessed via special functions(like `copy_from_user`). BTW, exploring origin syscall may find, that it uses `move_addr_to_kernel` for deal with that pointer.

Answer (score 1):

The code is quite obviously wrong, and so is the approach. **What is the real goal here?**

You have:

```
asmlinkage int hijackConnect(struct sock *sk, struct sockaddr *uaddr,int     addr_len)
```

and use that to replace syscall entry for connect(). It should be obvious this cannot be correct - how is the userspace supposed to pass the pointer to a socket? Not to mention the connect system call accepts different arguments:

```
SYSCALL_DEFINE3(connect, int, fd, struct sockaddr __user *, uservaddr,
                int, addrlen)
```

The first argument is a file descriptor, not a pointer to a socket, so that unsurprisingly led to crashed.

However, the approach itself is fundamentally flawed. Since you try to call the actual connect() later, the kernel re-fetches data from userspace and an attacker could simply modify it to fix up whatever your code did. See http://www.watson.org/~robert/2007woot/ for more details.

Comment: Thanks, but could you explain the function signature of SYSCALL_DEFINE3. Because I have hard time understanding why it does not have return type and yet the function body returns int value.

Answer (score 0):

> If possible, I would like to know how to rewrite destination ip address so that I can redirect http requests to particular web sites.

This is a task best suited for the Linux netfilter (*i.e,* iptables) packet filtering framework.

Hijacking system calls is not a supported technique, and will result in system instability. In this specific case, it will fail *badly* on a 32-bit x86 kernel because `connect()` does not have its own system call number; instead, the `socketcall()` system call is used with `SYS_CONNECT` as its first parameter. The entry you're overwriting in the system call table is completely unrelated. (I believe it's actually the entry for `exit()`!)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've actually tried using Netfilter, and successfully blocked access to static ip web sites.(Dynamic IP is another problem). However, trying to redirect website to another site by changing destination IP of tcp header fails. Even after recalculating checksum. The clients (firefox, wget) keeps requesting to the original site as if it doesn't acknowledge the changes I made until time out occurs. That's when I thought I might be at much lower level than I need to be in order to achieve and decided to try changing IP at higher level which is connect system call.